# How to remove string from certain positions and add another string at that place using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to programming and I want to replace string from certain position and replace it with another string.

Consider I have string `"i am @hello"`.
I want to replace string starting from @ to cursor position.

I have the indexes to the `@` character and cursor position but I don't know how to do it with replace method.

Below is the snippet:

```
replace_string = (original_string, "someuser") => {

    let new_value;
    const string_to_cursor_position = original_string.substring(0, 
        this.state.cursor_position);
    const at_char_position = string_to_cursor_position.lastIndexOf('@');

    return this.value.replace(this.state.cursor_position, 
    value_selected);
}
```

But this doesn't replace the string. The final output should be 
`"i am someuser"`.

Could someone help me fix this thanks.

Comment: `"i am @hello"` is `original_string` or `this.value`? `(original_string, "someuser")` is incorrect syntax, do you want to set default value of some variable to "someuser"? `new_value` and `at_char_position` is unused and `value_selected` is not set. What is `this.state.cursor_position`? 11 since `@hello` is at the end of string of length 11?

Comment: after `@` upto what it should replace ? do you have a list of allowed characters ? should it match upto the next space character ? or should it match only alphanumeric and `_`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace with regex.

```js
var myString = "i am @hello";
var replacingString = "someuser";

console.log(myString.replace(/@(\w+)/g, replacingString));
```

What the `/@(\w+)/g` regex expression does is:

- Finds the `@` character
- Once the `@` is found, gets the one word after that character. `(\w+)`
- Repeat any time it finds an `@` followed by a word. `g` flag

All the matches of this expression are replaced by the replace funciton.

**Edit:**

As @Jan pointed out in the comments, using `\S+` instead of `\w+` might work better in your case.

The difference between the two expressions is that `\S+` matches matches any non-whitespace character (basically words with "weird" characters between letters, like `-`)

Comment: How does this fit in with the OP's code (the cursor position, for example)?

Comment: how can i modify this such that it matches only the last @character? thanks

Comment: @stackoverflow_user with a [pisitive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The expression would be something like this: `/\@(\w+)(?=[^@(\w+)]*$)/g`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use replace and it's callback

[image]

```js
let replace_string = (original_string, replaceBy) => {
  return original_string.replace(/@\w+/, replaceBy)
}

console.log(replace_string("i am @hello", 'someuser'))
```

I have deliberately left `g` flag, if you want to replace all the strings after which are preceded by `@` you can use `/@\w+/g`

Comment: @Jan true, not sure what all OP is wiling to allow after after `@` so just kept it `\w+`

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use regular expressions for this kind of tasks.

if you want to replace from the `@` character to the next whitespace character you can simply do

```
yourstring.replace(/@[^\s]+/, "Replacement String")
```

or

```
yourstring.replace(/@[\S]+/, "Replacement String")
```

for example

```
const template = "I am @username";
const result = template.replace(/@[^\s]+/, "Ki Jéy")
```

Comment: `[^\s]+` is equal to `\S+` where the latter is more readable.